# Move a row to a column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like below and I want to transpose the value on `column_1` where `column_2` is `Null` to the next row `column_3` until the next `Null` value on `column_2`.

```
------------------------------------------------------
| ID  |Column_1 |Column_2|Column_3                   |
------------------------------------------------------
|1    |Deposit  |Null    |                           |
|2    |01/02    |Charges |value from column_2 of id=1|
|3    |02/02    |payable |value from column_2 of id=1|
|4    |operation|Null    |                           |
|5    |02/03    |Charges |value from column_2 of id=4|
|6    |03/03    |receive |value from column_2 of id=4|
```

Comment: In a query or in a stored procedure to generate a new table?

Comment: `value from column_2 of id=1` is `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select ID, Column_1, Column_2,
  max(c3) over(partition by partby) as Column_3
from (
  select
    *,
    iif(Column_2 is null, Column_1, null) as c3,
    sum(iif(Column_2 is null, 1, 0)) over(order by ID) as partby
  from t1
) as a;
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/VWA13378).

Answer (score 0):

Try this below script using Sub-Query-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f91b87688a201ccb6667e756c8d0ad0)

```
SELECT *,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
    CASE 
        WHEN A.Column_2 IS NULL THEN NULL 
        ELSE Column_1 
    END
    FROM your_table B
    WHERE B.ID < A.ID 
    AND B.Column_2 IS NULL
    ORDER BY ID DESC
) Column_3                   
FROM your_table A
ORDER BY ID
```